# can't start ncat on win64 - need to install libeay32.dll

Tags: networking, software-rec

i m trying to use small utility ncat on win64 machine.

it gives me errors:

```
can't continue executing this code. Need SSLEAY32.dll and LIBEAY32.dll. Try reinstalling
```

how to fix it? how to run ncat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How to fix it?

> ```
> can't continue executing this code. Need SSLEAY32.dll and LIBEAY32.dll. Try reinstalling
> ```

The statically compiled version does not require any access to external DLLs.

> Many users have asked for a statically compiled version of ncat.exe that they **can just drop on a Windows system and use without having to run any installer or copy over extra library files**. We have built a statically compiled Windows binary version of Ncat 5.59BETA1. You can download it inside a zip file [here](http://nmap.org/dist/ncat-portable-5.59BETA1.zip). To ensure the file hasn't been tampered with, you can check the cryptographic signatures. If you need a portable version of a newer Ncat release, see the Ncat portable compilation instructions.

<sup>emphasis mine</sup>

Source: [Ncat - Netcat for the 21st Century](https://nmap.org/ncat/)

Comment: this worked! thx u! i tried many other things - but only this worked